# Windows Service pegging cpu at 100% periodically, possible method to handle this situation?

Tags: c#, windows-services, cpu-usage

I have a windows service that I am partially responsible for writing.  It is semi-complex, creating a bunch of images on the fly which are later fed to a web application.

So, periodically it pegs the cpu to 100%.  I have previously ran Ants Profiler on it to fix a bunch of memory leak issues due to lack of disposing objects etc.

Now probably about once a day it pegs the cpu on the machine to 100%, and really creates a lot of havoc throughout the system.  I have seen this post that specifically deals with troubleshooting this specific situation. :

[Windows Service Increasing CPU Consumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148/windows-service-increasing-cpu-consumption)

I am not going to say I am past troubleshooting as I will continue to do so, but I will say is I am looking for other options.  Basically, ways to deal with this situation in the meantime.

For instance, is there a way I can monitor cpu usage within the service itself and upon the return of a 100% pegged cpu automatically restart the service?  Or possibly run a script or bat file via a task scheduler that is constantly checking for this scenario and when present restarts the service?  I know these are not great solutions, but currently I am looking for the best non root cause solution I can find.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the GC (Garbage Collector) might be kicking in and compacting a lot of memory.  If that is the case you might be able to allocate fixed sized buffers that are reused for your image work.  Have you tried something like perfmon?

Comment: Yes, perfmon has been used in the past, the troubleshooting has gone on for a period of time almost on the scale of a year.